# Remove class when li already have specific class

Tags: jquery

I have a mega menu and when mouseover item from menu a list is opened and first element start with 'active' class, but I need to remove this when mouseover in another .item-menu li from this list.

```
    <ul>
        <li class="mega-drop-down">
            <ul class="item-menu">
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down">
            <ul class="item-menu">
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

<script>
$(".mega-drop-down").mouseover(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        $("ul.item-menu li:first-child").addClass('active');
    });
    
    $(function () {
      $('ul.item-menu li').on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `this.parent.siblings.removeClass(active)` then add active class to the desired component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this I guess it may solve your purpose:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".mega-drop-down li").mouseover(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    
     $('ul.item-menu li').on('mouseleave', function () {
      $("ul.item-menu li").removeClass('active');
      });
    })
```

```css
.item-menu li{
  background:tomato;
  padding:20px 20px;
}
.active{
  background:green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="mega-drop-down">
            <ul class="item-menu">
                <li class="active">a</li>
                <li>b</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down">
            <ul class="item-menu">
                <li>c</li>
                <li>d</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```